# Ionic 2+ and Greensock = completely distorted animation

Tags: angular, animation, ionic3, gsap

So I'm trying to get this animated logo to work in an Ionic 3 app. I'm doing it the hacky way since from what I've read, the TypeScript version of Greensock doesn't work.

The short of it is that code that almost identical code that [works outside Ionic](https://jsfiddle.net/acfxxmau/13/) (JS Fiddle demo link) doesn't work [inside Ionic](http://plnkr.co/edit/BQodqzAfzGD6kZMI4nT5?p=preview) (Plnkr demo link), and I can't figure out why. If you're experienced with Greensock, you might be able to identify the issue just by looking at the two demos.

I've added my imports to the necessary javascript for Greensock into my index.html file and then in the component that uses the animations, I tell typescript about  the required JS functions by declaring them before the @Component:

```
declare var Bendy_setup:any;
declare var Bendy_action:any;

@Component({
  selector: 'bendy',
  templateUrl: 'bendy.html'
})
```

In my component template is the necessary sprites:

```
<div id="BendyStage" >
  <div id="spriteContainer" class="animElement">
    <img class="bendySprite bendyStatic" src="/assets/bendy-sprites/bendy_static.png">
    <img class="bendySprite animatedSprite" src="/assets/bendy-sprites/B_A_bendy_bookmark.png">
    <img class="bendySprite animatedSprite" src="/assets/bendy-sprites/B_A_bendy_intro.png">
    <img class="bendySprite animatedSprite" src="/assets/bendy-sprites/B_A_first_bookcase.png">
    <img class="bendySprite animatedSprite" src="/assets/bendy-sprites/B_A_hear_it_again.png">
    <img class="bendySprite animatedSprite" src="/assets/bendy-sprites/B_A_letsplay_lg.png">
    <img class="bendySprite animatedSprite" src="/assets/bendy-sprites/B_A_lg_Instructions.png">
    <img class="bendySprite animatedSprite" src="/assets/bendy-sprites/B_A_now_its_time.png">
    <img class="bendySprite animatedSprite" src="/assets/bendy-sprites/B_A_want_one_more.png">
    <img class="bendySprite animatedSprite" src="/assets/bendy-sprites/B_M_blink.png">
    <img class="bendySprite animatedSprite" src="/assets/bendy-sprites/B_M_look_around.png">
    <img class="bendySprite animatedSprite" src="/assets/bendy-sprites/B_M_poke.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

And in bendy.scss are the relevant CSS styles:

```
.bendySprite{
    position: absolute;
    height:100%;
    width: auto;
    shape-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(1000px);
}
.animatedSprite{
    display: none;
}
.animElement{
    position: absolute;
}
```

Then in `ngAfterContentInit` in `Bendy.ts` I'm calling the declared functions that should cause the animation to begin. What happens though is I get this completely distorted mess rather than an animation. Identical code taken out of the ionic project works perfectly.

I've created two demos to illustrate the issue.

Here's a demo of the code working outside Ionic: https://jsfiddle.net/acfxxmau/13/

And here's the same code NOT working in a boilerplate Ionic project: http://plnkr.co/edit/BQodqzAfzGD6kZMI4nT5?p=preview

Does anyone have any idea why this isn't working? I've tried using CSS's `all: unset` in a wrapper div to remove any inherited styles that could be messing this up but I'm not sure if I used it correctly.

I've also tried calling the functions in `ngOnInit` rather than `ngAfterContentInit` to no effect.